# Conflicting operation in read/write semantics vs. object semantics

Tags: concurrency, semantics

What (in simple terms) is the meaning of read/write semantics and of object semantics? Why is the following statement true?

> Debit/credit write to bank accounts and are defined to conflict under read/write semantics whereas under object semantics they do not.

Comment: My guess is that you're probably someone I know, as I'm looking for exactly the same answer from this past paper...

Comment: Can you give some more context for this question? For example, where did you encounter these terms? Was it in a book or article that you can cite? Can you quote a little more of it?

Comment: It was from a Cambridge University past paper exam question. It is discussing the use of TSO in concurrency control, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, I'm not sure if this answers the question.

Section 2.1-2 in the below PDF provides an overview.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.4184&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Here are some key points.

Read/Write

"The two phase locking protocol for read/write model maintains two types of lock for each object, namely read lock and write lock. A transaction must obtaion a read(write) lock before it can read(write) a data object. Two locks from different transactions conflict if both locks are applied on the same data object and at least one of them is a write lock. A transaction cannot obtain a lock if the lock conflicts with any other lock on that data object."

So you cannot read if another is writing or write if another is reading. But you can read if another is reading.

Object

"An object maintains a state and provides a set of operation that act as the sole means for transactions to access and modify the state of the object. ... Two commutative operations can be executed concurrently even when both the operations are update operations."

Now you can allow reads/writes for things where the order of operations are not of consequence.

They go on to explain how a deposit and withdraw will not commute(withdraw could be denied for insufficient funds), but two deposits can commute. These two deposits would block each other and have to occur in sequence under read/write but under object semantics they can occur concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering you've put "(in simple terms)"... I'll have a stab at this.

Firstly, this question makes most sense when referring to a "value" or "data" as an object. This is a typical way to discuss data in an OODB. Thus, a stored bank account balance is referred to as a "data object", and you can acquire a lock to access that value (read it, write it, delete it, etc.)

Given that context: read/write semantics are "the meaning of changing the data", based upon which we can make decisions about which reads or writes can happen within the locked transaction. In contrast, object semantics allow that you can mutate the value in any way you see fit as long you hold the relevant lock.

For a bank account, you want locking which doesn't allow both a debit and a credit (or even multiple debits, or multiple credits) to happen in the same transaction (so they continue to be seen as distinct operations). This means that your read/write semantic defines multiple credits/debits to conflict.

e.g. If, in the scope of a single transaction, I credit £10 to the bank account and debit £7 from the bank account (i.e. using object semantics), the resulting bank statement would show a single credit of £3, instead of the two separate entries.

By defining a locking logic using a read/write semantic, you can ensure that transactions don't get combined in this way.